# NaturalSize of AVAsset is different than video file

Tags: ios, swift, video, avasset

I have big problem with checking video orientation. There is a code to check if the video file is in portrait mode:

```
private func checkIfVideoIsPortrait(videoURL: NSURL) -> Bool {

    let videoAsset = AVAsset.init(URL: videoURL)
    let videoTrack = videoAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)[0]
    let size = videoTrack.naturalSize
    let txf = videoTrack.preferredTransform

    let realSize = CGSizeApplyAffineTransform(size, txf)

    print(videoTrack)
    print(txf)
    print(size)
    print(realSize)

    if (size.width == txf.tx && size.height == txf.ty) {
        return false
    } else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == 0) {
        return false
    } else if (txf.tx == 0 && txf.ty == size.width) {
        return true
    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

I have two video files: 1080x1920 and 360x640. The point is that the code return different dimensions of the files and I couldn't recognize what is the video orientation.

There are a logs:

**< AVAssetTrack: 0x157dee9a0, trackID = 2, mediaType = vide >**

**CGAffineTransform(a: 1.0, b: 0.0, c: 0.0, d: 1.0, tx: 0.0, ty: 0.0)**

**(320.0, 568.0)**

**(320.0, 568.0)**

**< AVAssetTrack: 0x1593643c0, trackID = 2, mediaType = vide >**

**CGAffineTransform(a: 0.0, b: 1.0, c: -1.0, d: 0.0, tx: 720.0, ty: 0.0)**

**(1280.0, 720.0)**

**(-720.0, 1280.0)**

How to check correctly dimensions of the video? I will be glad for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many days of trying and thinking how to get real natural size of the video I changed my strategy.

Right now I am using a thumbnail created from video to check the dimensions of the film.

The problem is in the AVAssetExportSession. It destroys preferredTransform and use a landscape values. The reason could be hidden in AVAssetExportPreset640x480.

There is a solution code in Swift 2.0:

```
func checkIfVideoIsPortrait(videoURL: NSURL) -> Bool {

    let videoAsset = AVAsset.init(URL: videoURL)

    let generator = AVAssetImageGenerator.init(asset: videoAsset)
    let imageRef: CGImageRef!

    do {
        try imageRef = generator.copyCGImageAtTime(kCMTimeZero, actualTime: nil)

        let thumbinal = UIImage.init(CGImage: imageRef)

        if thumbinal.size.width < thumbinal.size.height {
            return true
        } else if thumbinal.size.width > thumbinal.size.height{
            return false
        }

    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to check video portrait")
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
    return false
}
```